# Suppose $f$ is continuous and differentiable on $[0,1]$, that $0\le f(x)\le1$ for each $x\in[0,1]$, and that $f'(x)\neq1$ for each $x\in[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that there is at most one solution of $f(x)=x$ in $[0,1]$

I have started off with this:

There is at most one point $x$ such that $f(x)=x$

Suppose there are points $a,b\in[0,1]$, where $a\neq b$ such that $f(a)=a, f(b)=b$

By the Mean Value Theorem, there is a point $c\in(a,b)$ such that:

$f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(c)$

Therefore:

$b-a=(b-a)f'(c)$

$f'(c) =1$

Contradiction! As $f'(x) \neq 1$

Therefore there is at most one solution of $f(x)=x$ as required.

I'm unsure how to finish this off or if I'm going in the correct direction, any help?

Comment: @Studzinski please see my edit above. Is that okay?

Comment: your answer is perfect. You should just add suppose there are two distinct points $a,b$ so that you can cancel the factor $(b-a)$ in both sides.

Answer (score 0):

this is easier to see if you draw a unit square with the the opposite corners at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1).$ draw the diagonal $y = x$ too.

first let us establish that the solution $f(x) = x, 0 \le x \le 1$ is unique if $f'(x) \neq 1.$ this easily follows from the mean value theorem. for, suppose there are $a \neq b, f(a) = a, f(b) = b.$  then by mvt, $f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} = 1.$ a contradiction.

now, the graph of $y=f(x)$ starts on the left side $x = 0, 0 \le y \le 1$ and ends up on the right side $x = 1, 0 \le y \le 1.$

first let us get rid of the two easy cases of a constant $f$ and the case of $f(0) = 0, f \neq 0.$

we are left with the case that $0 < f(0) \le 1.$ by the intermediate value theorem applied to $f(x) - x$ shows that the graph $y = f(x)$ must cross the diagonal. by uniqueness, there is only one crossing.